# Class attribute not updating when using property decorators

Tags: python, class

I am trying to use property decorator to validate python object.

Following is my class

```
'''Contains all model classes. Each class corresponds to a database table'''

from validation import company_legal_type, max_len

class Company():
    '''A class to represent a company and its basic information'''
    
    def __init__(self, ref, name, currency, legal_type, business):
        self._ref = int(ref)
        self._name = name
        self._currency = str(currency) # i.e. The functional currency
        self._legal_type = str(legal_type)
        self._business = str(business)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Company object for '{self._name}'"
    
    # Validate object attributes

    @property # Prevents change to ref after company object has been created
    def ref(self):
        return self._ref

    @property # The following two functions permit changes but set validation checks for name
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if type(value) != str:
            raise TypeError("Company name must be a string.")
        if len(value) > max_len['company_name']:
            raise ValueError(f"Company name must not be longer than {str(max_len['company_name'])} characters.")
```

Following is validation.py

```
# data length validation
max_len = {
    'company_name': 200,
    'company_business': 200,
}
```

And finally here is how I am using the class:

```
# Import custom modules
from models import Company, Currency

company = Company(23, 'ABC Limited', 'PKR', 'pvt_ltd', 'manufacturing')    
company.name = 'ABCD Limited'

print(company.name)
```

This prints 'ABC Limited' instead of 'ABCD Limited'.

If I break a validation condition like use an integer instead of a string when updating company.name, it correctly results in an error. But if I break it when creating the object, no error is raised.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try creating a class variable outside the function at the beginning of the class named `company_name` and then assign it to the argument in the `__init__()`. This might change the output.

Comment: Because `def name(self, value):` **never sets anything**. Your setter doesn't act as a setter, it just throws an error if the input is bad, then does nothing.

Comment: "But if I break it when creating the object, no error is raised." Because *you don't use the property in `__init__`. Generally if you have validation property setters, you want to *use those in `__init__`*, so in `__init__` don't do `self._name = name` do `self.name = name`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So how may I solve this? If I use self.name, it results in max recursion error when I print company.name.

Comment: @mad_accountant *set something in the setter*. So `self._name` for the `name` setter. How else do you expect `self._name` to be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your setter *doesn't set anything*. It merely raises errors on bad input. So you *have to actually set something*, or else how do you expect it to modify `self._name`? So:

```
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    if type(value) != str:
        raise TypeError("Company name must be a string.")
    if len(value) > max_len['company_name']:
        raise ValueError(f"Company name must not be longer than {str(max_len['company_name'])} characters.")
    self._name = value
```

> If I break a validation condition like use an integer instead of a string when updating company.name, it correctly results in an error. But if I break it when creating the object, no error is raised.

Because *you don't use the property in `__init__`*. Generally if you have validation property setters, you want to *use those in `__init__`*. So your `__init__` should be something like:

```
def __init__(self, ref, name, currency, legal_type, business):
    self._ref = int(ref)
    self.name = name
    self._currency = str(currency) # i.e. The functional currency
    self._legal_type = str(legal_type)
    self._business = str(business)
```